# jQueryUI Draggable set originalPosition

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, user-interface

Does anyone know if it's possible to change the originalPosition attribute of a jQuery-UI draggable object so that the grid is calculated based on that position rather than the actual original position of the draggable?  I would like to set a draggable coming out of a tool bar of sorts to snap to the grid of a droppable container.  I have been unable to find out if this is even doable, although in theory it seems an obvious sort of extension of the draggable/droppable interaction.

Thanks

```
$('#draggable').draggable({
    start: function(e, ui) {
        ui.originalPosition = {"top":0,"left":0};
    }
}
```

Or something of the like.  See [This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dy8jd/), for an example that seems like it should work.

Comment: Can you provide your actual code?

Comment: Something like this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/dy8jd/

Answer (score 0):

```
ui.originalPosition.left = new_left;
ui.originalPosition.top  = new_top;
```

or

```
$.extend(ui.originalPosition, new_position)
```

This will work, because `ui.originalPosition` in jquery-ui is a reference to `this.originalPosition`.